# Classification of all groupoids $G$ whose automorphism group is in bijective correspondence the automorphism group of $C^*_\text{red}(G)$

Tags: c-star-algebras, noncommutative-geometry, groupoids

Is there a terminology (and a classification) for all groupoids $G$ for which all automorphisms of $C^*_\text{red}G$ are induced from a groupoid  automorphism of $G$.   (A groupoid automorphism has its natural obvious definition or it can be defined as an equivalence of the small category G.)

For example the groupoid arising from identification of $n$ points to a unique point would result in a matrix algebra. The automorphism group of a matrix algebra is larger than the discrete group associated to permutations of rows and columns.

But on this question we search for some examples (and possible classification) of groupoids with the mentioned property.

Comment: I tried to do some proofreading, including of the title which didn't compile, but I had trouble understanding some of the post.  If I got anything wrong, please feel free to roll back (but still to fix the title).

Comment: Of course a space, i.e., a groupoid made of units, satisfies your requirement.  On the other hand, any groupoid admitting a nontrivial cocycle does not. So this is a very rigid property.

Comment: For a discrete group $G$, one has that $C^*_{red}(G)$ satisfies this property iff $G$ is trivial.